# ConnectionService voip

Tags: android, sip, voip

I want to implement a Voip app with SIP protocol. I have managed receive  and dialing with the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip). The problem I have is, my app will not answer for the incoming call when it is closed. I have tried using services but not helping me solving the problem. I have seen ConnectionService in android documentation, but not clearly explain on how to implement. please give some tips how to solve this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: SIP runs over a wireless data connection, so your device must have a data connection (with a mobile data service or Wi-Fi).This means that, you can only test on a physical device.

Comment: Please share the code if possible... I always get error while registering Sip Profile

Answer (score -2):

This Android Project created by [Aentfs](https://github.com/Aentfs) called [Phony](https://github.com/Aentfs/Phony-Android) may help, give a look.